# Assignment evaluation order in GCC with C++17

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

C++17 defines the evaluation order in an assignment expression: the right-hand side evaluation and its side effects are sequenced-before the left-hand side evaluation and its side effects. However, the following code shows that this is violated in GCC for "aggregate assignments":

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Trivial {
  int x;
};

struct NonTrivial {
  constexpr NonTrivial(int x = 0) : x{x} { }

  int x;
};

constexpr int foo() {
  Trivial a[1]{};
  int i = 0;
  a[i++] = {+i};
  return a->x;
}

int postincrement(int& i) {
  std::cout << "postincrement\n";
  return i++;
}

int load(int& i) {
  std::cout << "load\n";
  return i;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "--aggregate assignment--\n";
  std::cout << std::integral_constant<int, foo()>() << '\n';
  std::cout << foo() << '\n';
  {
    Trivial a[1]{};
    int i = 0;
    a[i++] = Trivial{i * i};
    std::cout << a->x << '\n';
  }

  std::cout << "\n--is not even indeterminately sequenced--\n";
  {
    Trivial a[1]{};
    int i = 0;
    (std::cout << "LHS\n", a[postincrement(i)])
        = (std::cout << "RHS\n", Trivial{load(i)});
    std::cout << a->x << '\n';
  }

  std::cout << "\n--copy assignment OK--\n";
  // {
  //   NonTrivial a[1]{};
  //   int i = 0;
  //   a[i++] = NonTrivial{i};
  //   std::cout << a->x << '\n';
  // }
  {
    NonTrivial a[1]{};
    int i = 0;
    a[i++] = NonTrivial{*&i};
    std::cout << a->x << '\n';
  }

  std::cout << "\n--scalar assignment OK--\n";
  // {
  //   Trivial a[1]{};
  //   int i = 0;
  //   a[i++].x = +i;
  //   std::cout << a->x << '\n';
  // }
  {
    Trivial a[1]{};
    int i = 0;
    a[i++].x = +*&i;
    std::cout << a->x << '\n';
  }
}
```

The first printed value is 0, as expected. The second is 0 with O2, but 1 with O0. The third value is 1, the fourth example also shows that the right-hand side and left-hand side evaluation is interleaved (output `RHS LHS postincrement load 1`) and the code causes no warnings. The fifth to eighth, no longer using "aggregate assignment", are 0, with the ones commented out causing a warning and others not. Clang evaluates all outputs as 0 and shows no warnings. Msvc shows no warnings and disagrees only for the first, manifestly constant-evaluated output, as far as I can judge from the assembly. [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM9KuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIAAcAKykAA6oCoRODB7evv7SaRmOAiFhkSwxcUm2mPbFDEIETMQEOT5%2BATV1WY3NBKUR0bEJyQpNLW15nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1Cbbbk5jxJisJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenBACeKZgA%2BgTETEIChud0eDwuXgchwAKsQ8AA3PBiY4AdisD0Oh1CBEOqhO6MeKIAIvjQaCIVDwgJYQikbRUQTMWgGGNMKoUsRDlSGDTEWIINjcW8iYcNItDiBcSY0XjiQzUSSHqDMYK8dsCdKSeqyeD/pCcdzeXSAGLEVAsABKmCoDOVh2ZrPZnMNcL5tFN5qtVAgDpx2PMADYhScRWKJVKZZr5ZqdfcVYIpdqlcTSUqHr62RysQn%2BKgIOLpYyYa66YcmCZEhYuBWSWiY0m49m/cLRanG%2BXK3hrN3EiKQ7bLF2Uw3MZcCGsGGWALQ3NUalNp%2B6CwqOBjIS5sQQCwSBrEFusYw5jdAgFCrHEnNyX45mMwrvYbxgECtuBjmMxt0eYcfESddyzdg2MaLoKtCoEw6Dbs%2BZhBng%2B5Fsep5oF4F6nNe75gRBL5vren6HGOE5Ym2wFgkuCYsICDD5rah6IWeKFvFepw3mYU5TkwwDAJcwBMAQrxMAoGTAAwm4EGx2HvnhdHIahTFuEeBAniA2KYFxYg/L6hjPqc2KkIcub5jc1GXteYBbIkr5mVJilIeejHXgZBZocxVkWQwVkjjRjaYkayIdlWNaFvWRbxs2/YaHhmL%2Bf%2BVgAb2LaFkOWohQpSkyfZzFMDO2zYKoGXya5llbJ5JGYkFh4%2BSWfkVgFvZBcOKWCngLYRZ5UU1TFPZ9tsfZ1oOwV2pi0l2SZmXZbl%2BWHIV7nFUWpVeZilW0tVlbVnVdYNYNTZYi1kVlh13Zxd1Iq%2BbQiWHAAVERm0ValtkMaN8lZbOk3TR5c0LqRQ02fRsnobhblsXgCiHAwqA4pg8KMNmWB8cQLChLxtQfEemAAI5eIwGzoOJbmSSVB7ecWy30v5a21lYN1E01u1tYcEDDQ9znye%2BQQABJCBJt56f595ro%2BW5wTWixbYtLYMz96WPSxFoc1zZh6adhaYZBQvEiLdOM39Y0vdLb2zXaJF2lrk2SYDU5oCkKMCUJIlPocADyADSuOvvjH0pS6JP7atgUbclW00%2BFe3RYdVjxf2XtuolA23Sb0vPTleV6%2BZRV4fN5VE1HpZk37lMB7dQc9a2dOhwBR0JWiSV7fHzPTrrdf6%2Bnn1lYTYvZyttUU7H1MJs1welwd5fh8dXLUlVZ1ohdgbV5rksjXXicTSn2HvYbLcLYtHfumalrWj7Xf1QXvdhcXrUpWXsUjy228envVAx1TYu13J9dJ69qczc3iqNpn7fjyTO%2BXoD7kyPntIuoYQ5DyvjWSuFhZ4pRfteJeydG6fzXoeDObct4ALdEA/eud1r53AX3WmF9oFdRvrgk0u8vRBX6k/RaSCdbvxXm5DBv9PrG3nkzV%2BZtXxsQUKIAwnIbZ4GEqJR2LsZx41wgTFKp0QF5x7mLCBJdyGdjDjWAAdKgkUXY55pQXq/FBH9V4G0wRvP%2Bi1FGEO7ow0KO0B4aPgVo3suiEr9UMfdbWT1xqoNfk3AmP9W4KInkoohKjFpqPPltS%2BXUPH9mnjBAxiCeG%2BLfsvNB5jv7rzCd7OxYC6YxKgZo4eOi9E3gsMkgMqStrML8Q3QJ6CLGcJ/pqDgyxaCcESLwPwHAtCkFQJwK8w8jyrHWK8HYPBSAEE0J05YABrEA2wNDaMSPESQ8QNBmESFwAAnCieIAYzAon0JwSQfT5lDM4LwBQIANCzPmcsOAsAYCIBAGyTAyAUIkHIJQZowAFDKEMLUIQCBUAAHd%2BkzLQCwFIdBeJZBBWEWg4KoX9MGXChF9A4hAuYCkBQEKCCkGxXQWI4RWCbF4GS3FDsULouhdcr5yB7jECBbc0gLLGj4H6bwfgggRBiHYFIGQghFAqHUAMnQegDBGBQGHfQeAoj3MgMsVAKR6j3I4FOY8IZTDDy4CiQ4U4HZmBNQAdTEPSKcFq2T/CYJa746AtJ4GQJa60VADVX14KgKGxA4RYFVfmFYawNh6GPKEFFYKIVMu4LwSFAIUicB4F0npVzpU3I4Llb5vzOSqGOVOAMkhDjAGQO6iAeoGCLPFBAUZV89K4EICQG82wuCLF4HM6ViwlkgESGssw%2ByuDxEOZsxI%2BzEjbHORwS5pAWAgEkPs7R%2BzJDjtXSutda7pCYt9Zy%2B5jyu1aBee8iASAWV5v%2BRAQFwLQVotjTCml5ocVIoENGu9GLrm0uGPipghLiWkqfeS4glK2Ccq/cQelwh73MtUN8tlHKOC8G5YpUInKBXCGESK6Q6GJVqGuboBWcrjCKtoMq4N6rNVZG1bqxS%2Bqw5GpNQ7DQlrrUetUA6p1mAXWCDdR6qgXqw6%2Bv9YGzA5HQ2TIjShhgb7GUPtIIm39KbOnTt6aQHdWac0/KIPmwtxbS3lvplWmt9N63WEbfgbTrb22duecsBAVwsBxBDd0mdvB539u0RoRIkgvM%2Be875rzAY1PXOGYh2wDynndt7WYLg2ijlDskDBDQhzx0wWkC57YGbBmhZs920gryPnnu05e69MnoPxoA/CxF9QysfszeBlARGuABg0I88DIHqWVZxbESDsmYNwfZdqpDsHkA8tQ2F9DQrxCipw0oPDmbdBTqIwq4eSqVXwAo1qzgNH0B0cNca015rbWsdtfagEnHuOOHdad/j3rrBCdiCJsTCgJnhq4LYKTtW40zIU8m%2BNaaOCqfU6FzTebcS6ZLfsQwwBDjNc855kzirDhNss9MjtkWj12Yc8MENyzbzLq8zsxIJyfMHMndO2d86uCteC5mnL4WD3PPyyek9SBwOXoa/CZAKQUg/HhAcn4Bg%2BJjB%2BKoYtpAsCIg2AANTwJgSFDtvhyZoLQOG9yIBRGuVERGxAPhKdINr5guuHZRG0N8rtsLzSiQdgwWgevM1YCiF4YAbhrXapmVgCiRhxAO7wJcBwCJRP9a05sGZKkXODNI1EAEuuPBYGuf8PA87/t8AMEC2X8vFeMH15NzDEhsOyFw1KwZuh3vLbu5YNbYmNVbY4AAekQhXqsxq69moewGvAQaNtdHN1kFwDB3CeHaHoYIoRBgVGGO9womQBCTD8FP9IM%2BGBzCGHEd7dhe8CF6BMIfeR1%2B1E3w0cY/Qx/zEnx9voc/JOzFP6viQywXthpFQDoHIXOC4j0ywBQXPDj86XUL0THECAFHFtNHXLTHUgPHSQOLGLHZfZAIYtbYRdJbC5NzEAFEaA05HZFEbA3AmCWnbLPdCLQ9ZTArU9EAc8FIFCDnQDXFDrTgMXEtL/H/P/bRAAsYJDCzEgTvPQXPYVfPMVeQObYvGVd7X7JTF/LLXdDgSDKgnEVAG0Rgw4Zg91Vg9goAjwKrXFKzdHEgntUgezCCHHAHSnfwRIGAw5QdFEKwqw7YKdYHIgxnKLSA/IGA6nQdBAyQJA/ZFAjgTLAg6Q8AhZadMwKQrNII/Q/1DIZwSQIAA) with these and a few more cases.

I've seen several similar SO questions and GCC bug reports, but they are either many years old or concerned with excessive warnings while program behaviour is correct. I've tried to check relevant paragraphs in C++17 standard but haven't found any "aggregate assignment"-related exceptions to assignment expression evaluation order.

Before submitting a bug report I wanted to make sure that I haven't missed anything. Is GCC (and msvc) behaviour indeed incorrect?

Comment: The analysis of `a[i++] = {i, 0};` is complicated... one isn't quite sure if the initializer_list contains an lvalue `i` or an rvalue `i`.  In the lvalue case, `i` will be read in the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, after `a[i++]` is evaluated to an lvalue.  However this uncertainly can be excluded by `a[i++] = {+i, 0};` where the braced list clearly contains two prvalues.... and the behavior still varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard only says that evaluation of the right-hand operand is sequenced before evaluation of the left-hand operand.

However, in the right-hand operand `{i, 0}` or `{i}` the only relevant evaluation is `i` without any lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, i.e. the value of `i` is never read in that evaluation.

The value of `i` is only read later for the call to `operator=(X&&)` (`X` being either `Trivial` or `NonTrivial`) which the assignment resolves to, in order to construct the temporary object from `{i, 0}` to bind the `X&&` parameter to.

The standard only makes statements about the evaluation of the "*operand*". It is not clear to me whether or not this would include the temporary construction (or any conversions applied to such operands for that matter).

Comment: I haven't considered that, thank you. However, as @BenVoigt points out forcing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion doesn't seem to affect GCC behaviour at all, I've updated the question.